# sudo apt update problem

Tags: networking, apt, system-installation, sudo

```
valenton@valenton:~$ sudo apt update
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ jammy: /usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key != /usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.
valenton@valenton:~$
```

Comment: Looks like you added your winehq source incorrectly. Go back to the winehq instructions, review what you did, locate your error, and fix it.

Comment: Or, even better, do NOT use the WineHQ PPA and simply install Wine from the official Ubuntu repository. It's not the latest version but should fit 99% of everyone's needs.